# Network Problem in Android x86

Tags: internet, 8.1-oreo

I dual booted Android x86 8.1 iso in PC. Everything went nice but when I set it up it was not getting network. I am using USB device for internet connection. Can anyone please tell how to fix it?

Comment: An "USB device for Internet connection" is not very specific, therefore nobody will be able to help you. When writing questions be as precise as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by USB device for internet connection? Are you using a dongle with a SIM card? If so then those dongles need their respective software to connect to PC which are (in most cases) only available for Windows.

If that is not the case, try these steps.

In a terminal, type:

```
sudo vi /etc/init.sh
```

add 4 lines below to init.sh

```
netcfg eth0 dhcp
echo nameserver <ip> > /etc/resolv.conf
dnsmasq 
setprop net.dns1 8.8.8.8
```

Comment: Yes, its a dongle.

Comment: There have been many discussion in the past about this topic & without a straightforward solution. There is a hack solution by first recognising the dongle under Linux to get the chat-scripts. For a detailed guide, have a read on XDA Forum: https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/development/guide-huawei-usb-3g-modem-android-x86-4-t2829533